# How to secure my angular js app code, which may stolen from browser's source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a one angular js app. The end user of my application is able to show app code from the browser's source code. How can I prevent this?

Is there any solution available by which I can hide or encrypt the code of my app?

Comment: You can try to make it hard to read, but it never prevent those really wants.

Comment: all the code you provide, compiled or not, is never protected. Once one has access to the application, he will always be able to decompile it, whatever the language etc... Uglify is just making them harder the task, but there are already plenty of tools able to un-uglify. What you need is to add the correct security on your backend, and manage CORS correctly.

Comment: you can use https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home approach to make your code difficult else there is no way you can encrypt your code

Answer (score 5):

Given Angular JS is javascript code run on the user's browser, everything will be available for the end user to inspect and tamper. Some of the below methods will make it difficult for a user to decompile and read the original source code:

1. JS Obfuscation tools
2. Uglify & Minify JS

**Advanced tip**: You can try using web assembly files (*.wasm) where you can write the code in C,C++ etc and compile it into .wasm file and include in the browser. This will help you to a certain extent, but even this method isn't complete fool-proof.

Comment: Like you said, it's not fool-proof at all. wasm is already human readable, and can thus easily be "decompiled" into a language of your choice. wasmdec does this, for example. https://github.com/wwwg/wasmdec

Answer (score 0):

You can only minify and uglify which renames the variables/functions, as the JS has to be executed on the browser. You can use [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) to do this.

However, you can also explore/consider using a commercial tool like [jScrambler](https://jscrambler.com) which seems to have capabilities to protect JS